# Get Atttribute value from XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get the ResponseCode attribute value out of this XML.

The XML is an XDocument

```
    <IDMResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="1" xmlns="http://www.fake.org/namespace/">
    <ARTSHeader>
        <Response ResponseCode="Rejected">
            <RequestID>1</RequestID>
            <BusinessError Severity="Error">
                <Code>IdmInvalidUserNamePasswordLoginProvided</Code>
                <Description>Invalid username or password, if problem persists, please contact Administrator</Description>
            </BusinessError>
        </Response>
    </ARTSHeader>
</IDMResponse>
```

Comment: did u tried anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XPath: (No error checks done)

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsm.AddNamespace("def", "http://www.fake.org/namespace/");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string code = 
    doc
    .XPathSelectElement(@"/def:IDMResponse/def:ARTSHeader/def:Response", nsm)
    .Attribute("ResponseCode")
    .Value;
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    if(el.Name.ToString() == "ARTSHeader")
        foreach(XElement ell in el.Elements())
        {
            if(ell.Name.ToString() == "Response")
                string responseCode  = ele.Attribute("ResponseCode").Value;
        }
}
```

Does this work for you? I dont know the whole structure of your xml so you might need to go deeper into the nested xml to get to Response first

Answer (score 0):

One possible way :

```
.....
XNamespace ns = "http://www.fake.org/namespace/";
string responseCode = (string)doc.Descendants(ns+"Response")
                                 .First()
                                 .Attribute("ResponseCode");
Console.WriteLine(responseCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one out, I haven`t tested so you might need to rearrange some structure

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(soapResult); 
XNamespace ns1 = "http://www.fake.org/namespace/";
var items = doc1.Descendants(ns1 + "ARTSHeader").Descendants(ns1 + "Response").First().Attribute("ResponseCode").Descendants(ns1 + "BusinessError").First().Attribute("Severity")
               .Select((x) => new
                {
                    Code = x.Element(ns1 + "Code").Value,
                    Description = x.Element(ns1 + "Description").Value,

                });
```